# Differences between dir and ls FTP Commands

Tags: ftp

Hello we have made a little program to upload an .zip file to an FTP server, and when I connect to the FTP server with FileZilla to see everything is ok I can't see the uploaded file.

But if connect to the FTP by an ftp command in the windows shell and perform an ls command I can see the file, but if I instead use the dir command, the file is not listed (in fact, no one file is listed)

So that... what are the differences between these two commands (ls / dir)?

It seems that FileZilla is using the dir command.

Note: I don't know the which FTP server are using but whe i connect it responds "220 sasbas FTP server (Version 4.2 ....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `dir` and `ls` is that the under the hood the Windows FTP client is sending two different [FTP commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands).

The `dir` command sends the `LIST` FTP command:

> Returns information of a file or
>   directory if specified, else
>   information of the current working
>   directory is returned.

The `ls` command sends the `NLIST` FTP command:

> Returns a list of file names in a
>   specified directory.

This doesn't really explain the difference in the listing, but I would suggest looking into your FTP server's documentation to investigate why you would see different results for these two commands.

Comment: On GNU/Linux, `ls` displays the same informations as `dir`, I tried it on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. From `ftp` man page: `Print a listing of the contents of a directory on the remote machine. The listing includes any system-dependent information that the server chooses to include; for example, most UNIX systems will produce output from the command ‘ls -l’. (See also nlist.)`

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` returns a full directory listing whereas the `ls` returns a simplified directory listing.

Comment: But why dir is not listing the file as ls do?

Comment: Because it is two different commands. "dir" requests platform specific information when "ls" requests only filenames.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permissions oddity, and may be a platform specific issue. Can you tell us what OS and FTP server software is involved (many servers will announce this information as you connect).

If it responds to the command `ls -al`, could you add that information to your question? And/Or if you can connect the account using SSH what does `ls -al` return then?

One other thing - does the zip file have a dot as its first character? This is often interpreted as meaning the file should be hidden unless specifically you specify options otherwise.

Comment: i have added the FTP connection response to the question.

The ls -al command do not return anything and the zip file name doesn't start by dot.